# downloading a file from src/main/resource folder

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, io

I have a maven parent project--->vehicle. under that there a two projects: car, bike.
under car project--> src/main/resource folder there is a file abc.txt. In bike project i have a servlet class. From here i am downloading the abc.txt file. So for the code:

```
Strinf filePath = "";
```

what should be the value i need to pass to the filePath variable?

servlet complete code of doGet method :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            String filename = "abc.txt";
            String filepath = "";

            response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
                    + filename + "\"");

            // use inline if you want to view the content in browser, helpful for
            // pdf file
            // response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=\"" +
            // filename + "\"");
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filepath
                    + filename);

            int i;
            while ((i = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(i);
            }
            fileInputStream.close();
            out.close();
        }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html

Comment: (if someone finds a better duplicate => feel free)